# Auto create directories after uploading with PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a php site where a company will upload a lot of images. I'd like one folder to contain upto 500-1000 files and PHP automatically creates a new one if previous contains more that 1000 files.

For example, `px300` has folder `dir1` which stores 500 files, then a new one `dir2` will be created.

Are there any existed a solutions?

Answer (score 3):

This task is simple enough not to require an *existing solution*.  You can make use of [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to count the number of files in a directory, and then [mkdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to make a directory.

```
// Make sure we don't count . and .. as proper directories
if (count(scandir("dir")) - 2 > 1000) {
    mkdir("newdir");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to create one-letter directories based on the file name. This works particularly well if you assign random names to files (and random names are good to avoid name conflicts in user uploads):

```
/files/a/c/acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8
/files/3/7/37b51d194a7513e45b56f6524f2d51f2
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way:

```
if ($h = opendir('/dir')) {
    $files = 0;
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($h))) {
        $files++
    }
    if($files > 1000){
    //create dir
    mkdir('/newdir')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [glob](http://www.php.net/glob) function. It will return an array matching your pattern, which you could count for the amount of files.